# Hiding Certain Lines on Table

Tags: tables, formatting, line

I made the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\def\arraystretch{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|ccc|} \hline
         &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Actual} \\ \hline
         & Class & Low & Med. & High \\ \hline
         \multirow{3}{*}{Prediction} & Low & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
         & Med. & $10$ & $98$ & $1$ \\
         & High & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I am just curious if there is any way to get rid of the lines around the boxes that have nothing in them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of `multicol` here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|ccc|} 
    \cline{3-5}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Actual} \\ \cline{2-5}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Class & Low & Med. & High \\ \hline
     \multirow{3}{*}{Prediction} & Low & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
     & Med. & $10$ & $98$ & $1$ \\
     & High & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to omit all lines, looks better for me. In the following mwe I show both versions. Please see my pretty printing to be able to see the structure of the table faster  ...

MWE [important code changings marked with `<======`]:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\def\arraystretch{1.5}
How about without lines:

\begin{tabular}{c c ccc} %\hline    
                              &       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Actual} \\ %\hline
                              & Class & Low  & Med. & High \\ %\hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{Prediction} & Low   & $0$  & $0$  & $0$ \\
                              & Med.  & $10$ & $98$ & $1$ \\
                              & High  & $0$  & $0$  & $0$ \\ %\hline
\end{tabular}

Version with lines:

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|ccc|} \cline{3-5} % <==============================
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{}                & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Actual} \\ \cline{2-5} % <===========
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}       & Class & Low  & Med. & High \\ \hline % <========
  \multirow{3}{*}{Prediction} & Low   & $0$  & $0$  & $0$  \\ % <=======
                              & Med.  & $10$ & $98$ & $1$  \\
                              & High  & $0$  & $0$  & $0$  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: result]